# When I read from a .txt file and reach to last line, How can I turn to first line

Tags: vb.net

I am reading from txt file line by line and writing to another txt file. When it reach to end, I need to go back to first line. Currently when the code that I wrote reach the last line, it is not turning to first line automatically and not continuing to reading.

I tried to close the file and open it again. I failed with that.

```
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(dosya, FileMode.Open)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)
    Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream(dosya1, FileMode.Append)
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs1)
```

Comment: Did you try `fs.Position = 0L`? Docs: [FileStream.Position Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.position?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Or something like `File.AppendAllLines(dosya1, File.ReadAllLines(dosya))
File.AppendAllLines(dosya2, File.ReadAllLines(dosya)) ...`. Unless those files contain a large number of lines of text. If not, you can also store the result of `File.ReadAllLines(dosya)` and append text to other files (list of files) in a loop. The `File.ReadLines()` method can be used, too. It can yield lines of text to `File.AppendAllLines()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to read lines from one file and repeatedly write them to another. Here are a few ways to accomplish this.

The hard way:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(dosya)
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(dosya1, True)

        For index = 1 To 10

            'Read every line from the StreamReader and write to the StreamWriter.
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
            Do While line IsNot Nothing
                sw.WriteLine(line)
                line = sr.ReadLine
            Loop

            'Go back to the beginning of the Stream.
            sr.DiscardBufferedData()
            sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

The simple way:

```
Dim input As String = File.ReadAllText(dosya)

Using sw As New StreamWriter(dosya1, True)
    For index = 1 To 10
        sw.Write(input)
    Next
End Using
```

The simplest way (and the least efficient, because with every loop it has to re-read the first file and open the second file for writing):

```
For index = 1 To 10
    File.AppendAllLines(dosya1, File.ReadAllLines(dosya))
Next
```

@Jimi makes a good remark: if your file is too big to fit in memory, the second and third options might not be usable.